# How Resolve Error Firebase Flutter Application ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I create the project use flutter and firebase, and i cnt run this project cause error

Restarted application in 2,847ms.

```
E/flutter ( 5630): \[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)\] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)  
E/flutter ( 5630): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)  
E/flutter ( 5630): \<asynchronous suspension\>
E/flutter ( 5630): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 5630): \<asynchronous suspension\>
E/flutter ( 5630): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31) 
E/flutter ( 5630): \<asynchronous suspension\>
E/flutter ( 5630): #3      main (package:flutter_firebase/main.dart:7:3)
E/flutter ( 5630): \<asynchronous suspension\>
E/flutter ( 5630):
```

this my error if i run the project

[image]

i can connect to firebase idk

Comment: You have to add this line before initiliaze firebase app.  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); and check

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to initialize Firebase in `main()` function. Add Below two lines at the start of the `main()` function.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // <-- Add this
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); //<-- Add this
```